# Python 3: simple unicode error, how to fix?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-unicode

I'm trying to run the following script:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request

url = 'http://www.espnfc.com/spi/rankings/_/view/fifa/teamId/203/mexico?cc=5901'
page = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read(), "html.parser")
print(soup)
```

And I get stuck on this message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/ashkij/Documents/Programming/Python Stuff/from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup.py3", line 9, in <module>
    print(soup)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xa0' in position 19458: ordinal not in range(128)
[Finished in 1.4s with exit code 1]
[cmd: ['python3', '-u', '/Users/ashkij/Documents/Programming/Python Stuff/from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup.py3']]
[dir: /Users/ashkij/Documents/Programming/Python Stuff]
[path: /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin]
```

Comment: Does not raise an error for me. Include the full traceback.

Comment: Maybe you should try decoding with a specific charset `soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read().decode('utf-8'), "html.parser")`

Comment: The problem is with your console encoding. You need to use a more capable console or fix your settings.

Comment: (I updated the description to include the full error.) 

I fixed the error by changing `print(soup)` to `print(soup.encode("utf-8"))`

I'm still a Python starter, and was wondering how, exactly, to format the fix to apply to `print(soup.prettify())`    ? 

How do I encode that^ like I did with the `print(soup)` fix?

Comment: Probably `soup.prettify().encode("utf-8")`